# How to update a conditional formula?

Tags: r, formula

let me jump right into the example. Consider the following equation:

```
 frml <- formula(y ~ a + b | x + z )
```

Such a formula specification is used e.g. with `AER::ivreg`.

I would like to update this formula so that it reads

```
 frml2 <- y ~ a + b + c | x + z + w
```

However, I am not sure how to update the parts before and after the conditional sign `|` separately. For instance,

```
 frml2 <- update.formula(frml, . ~ . + c | . + w)
```

gives

```
 y ~ ((a + b | x + z) + c | (a + b | x + z) + w)
```

which is not quite what I want. The problem is that `.` refers to the entire formula on the right (or left) side, including the conditional. Does anyone have an idea how I can update the formula accordingly?

One way seems to be to convert the formula into a character vector, split the vector at `|`, add whatever I want to add, and put the formula back together. While this is easy, somehow I feel that there must be an easier way to do so. I surely am not the first person to deal with this kind of issue. Any advice / hint / comment would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Can't tell for sure from your question if you cannot use a package, because the `Formula` package has a function just for this. It classes its objects as both `formula` and `Formula`:

```
> library(Formula)
> frml <- Formula(y ~ a + b | x + z )
> update(frml, . ~ . + c | . + w)
y ~ a + b + c | x + z + w
> class(frml)
[1] "Formula" "formula"
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's method that doesn't require an external package. It uses the structure of a formula:

```
 frml[[3]][[2]] <- quote(a+b+c)
 frml[[3]][[3]] <- quote(x + z + w)
 frml
#y ~ a + b + c | x + z + w
```

Although displayed with infix formalism, the storage of a formula object uses R functions and lists. A formula's first component (like that of any function call) is the "~", the second is the LHS expression and the third is the RHS. Likewise the RHS in this case is also structured similarly with the `"|"` as the first element, since `"|"` is a logical function with two arguments. So you want to target the 2nd and third elements of the 3rd element of the object. So those are `frml[[3]][[2]]` and `frml[[3]][[3]]`. You need to pass in a language value which the `quote` function performs. The formula object can also be express in a more "functional" version:

```
 identical(frml,   # after the mods
            `~`(y, `|`(a + b + c, x + z + w)),
            ignore.environment=TRUE)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks for that trick! I like the `quote`-trick. I previously converted formulae to characters and manipulated them that way, but this is much better. Thanks!